# kivy jnius Class not found

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, kivy

I search kivy bluetooth example, find these code, and copy paste, but not work. What should I  do solve problem. Thanks.

version:

python: 2.7

kivy: 1.9

jnius: 1.0.2

source: https://gist.github.com/tito/7432757

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frank/workspace/798/bluetooth.py", line 13, in <module>
    BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
  File "/home/frank/package/kivyPython2Venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jnius/reflect.py", line 106, in autoclass
    c = find_javaclass(clsname)
  File "jnius_export_func.pxi", line 23, in jnius.find_javaclass (jnius/jnius.c:7190)
jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter'
```

bluetooth.py

```
from jnius import autoclass

BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')

def get_socket_stream(name):
    paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
    socket = None
    for device in paired_devices:
        if device.getName() == name:
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            recv_stream = socket.getInputStream()
            send_stream = socket.getOutputStream()
            break
    socket.connect()
    return recv_stream, send_stream

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: '0'
        on_release: app.reset([b1, b2, b3, b4, b5])
    ToggleButton:
        id: b1
        text: '1'
        on_release: app.send(self.text)
    ToggleButton:
        id: b2
        text: '2'
        on_release: app.send(self.text)
    ToggleButton:
        id: b3
        text: '3'
        on_release: app.send(self.text)
    ToggleButton:
        id: b4
        text: '4'
        on_release: app.send(self.text)
    ToggleButton:
        id: b5
        text: '5'
        on_release: app.send(self.text)
    '''
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.app import App

    class Bluetooth(App):
        def build(self):
            self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = get_socket_stream('linvor')
            return Builder.load_string(kv)

        def send(self, cmd):
            self.send_stream.write('{}\n'.format(cmd))
            self.send_stream.flush()

        def reset(self, btns):
            for btn in btns:
                btn.state = 'normal'
            self.send('0\n')

    Bluetooth().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Qpython you also have to import Kivy because PyJnius is only a part of Kivy. in this case use:

```
#qpy:kivy
from jnius import autoclass
```

if you have compiled your own distribution with Py4A, I think you have a error while compiling it.